# How to access button image name?

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, uibutton

I am trying to access my button image name and check its value using if and then set another image to that button

[image: 1]

Comment: Please elaborate.

Comment: Do not post screenshot of code, copy/paste code instead.

Comment: First read : How do I ask a good question?   
      https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

Try this code,

```
   if (btn1.currentImage == [UIImage imageNamed:@"currentIcon.png"] ) 
    {

    }
    else
    {
    [btn1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"newIcon.png"] forState: UIControlStateNormal];
    }
```